# Selenium exited before it could start error while running WCT in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-pipeline, wct

I get errors while running WCT in the Jenkins pipeline. I share that errors detail on the bottom. These errors may be related to Openshift. Maybe you can share your opinion.

Note: My tests are running at Openshift.

**First case:** 
-> I running with a chrome configuration. In this case, I get the following error. This error message is clear. We must install chrome. But I don't know how to do it.

Error:

```
The following browsers were not found: chrome. (All installed browsers found: firefox)
```

Error image:

[image: Image-1]

**Second case:**

-> Because of the above error I changed browser configuration to firefox. But I take a different error this time. This error is complicated for me. I need more detail about this error. According to my research, there may be many reasons for this. Maybe we should add/change some options on Openshift.

> Note:
>
> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
>   -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true 10:12:47.767 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version:
>   3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358 10:12:47.857 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone
>   Selenium Server on port 33226 2019-11-12 10:12:47.903:INFO::main:
>   Logging initialized @385ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
>   10:12:48.154 INFO [WebDriverServlet.] - Initialising
>   WebDriverServlet 10:12:48.252 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium
>   Server is up and running on port 33226
>
> Waiting on this line too much. After that, I aborted the manual pipeline. Because the process does not continue.

Error:

```
Selenium exited before it could start
```

Error image:

[image: Image-2]

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
10:12:48.252 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 33226
Error: Selenium exited before it could start
```

...implies that the **Selenium Server** can't be started for some reasons (e.g. port 4444 is blocked).

As per the discussion [Selenium exited before it could start](https://github.com/webdriverio-boneyard/wdio-selenium-standalone-service/issues/10) this error can be observed when *Selenium Server* is started in another process before running npm/wdio and hence **selenium standalone service** will fail to start.

### Solution

The simplest solution would be to check for a running `selenium` process or try `killall` *selenium* / *java* processes.